# Swift: reference to generic type Range requires arguments in

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsrange

I'm trying to create a function to return Range but I'm getting this error:

reference to generic type Range requires arguments in...

This is my code:

```
func rangOfSubString(msgStr:String) -> Range {

   ...
}
```

Any of you knows why or a way to work around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Update your question with the complete error message and point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range` is a generic public struct as is defined here in `swift->Collection->Range`

```
public struct Range<Bound : Comparable>
{
  ....
}
```

so you need to specify the type of data that will have and must implement the comparable protocol, use something like this

```
func rangOfSubString(msgStr:String) ->Range<String.Index>
{

}
```

I hope this helps you